# Variation of algorithms to find point from another point with bearing and distance

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, spherical-geometry, bearing

There are several algorithms to calculate distance between two latitude/longitude points.

1. [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine)
2. Hubeny
3. [Lambert-Andoyer](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k94796k)
4. [Vincenty's formulae for inverse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Inverse_problem)

But there are not so many algorithms (actually I can't finally find it) which can calculate latitude/longitude of point B from another latitude/longitude point A with bearing and distance.

1. [Vincenty's formulae for direct problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem)

I'm glad to know if there are any algorithms which is lesser accurate, but faster than Vincenty's formulae.

Comment: The haversine formula is for the sphere. The analogous solution is based on spherical geometry; one set of formulas appears in the Wikipedia article on [solving triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles#Two_sides_and_the_included_angle_given).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a method which is both *more* accurate and faster?  This is
provided by [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sf.net).  Comparative timings (C++
implementations on a 2.66GHz Intel processor, using g++) are:

```
Vincenty direct:                          1.11 us
GeographicLib::Geodesic::Direct:          0.88 us
GeographicLib::GeodesicLine::Position:    0.37 us
GeographicLib::GeodesicLine::ArcPosition: 0.31 us
```

The accuracy of Vincenty's formulas is about 0.1 mm, while the accuracy
of the GeographicLib algorithms about 0.01 um.  Geodesic::Direct does a
straight solution of the direct problem.  It's somewhat faster than
Vincenty because it's non-iterative and because it uses Clenshaw
summation to evaluate the trigonometric series.  GeodesicLine::Position
allows you to calculate many points along a *single* geodesic about
2.4 times faster.  If you merely want some
points on a geodesic which are *approximately* equally spaced (e.g., for plotting it), you can use
GeodesicLine::ArcPosition and shave a little extra time off the
computation.  You can reduce the time still further by reducing the order of the
series used by GeographicLib from 6 to 3 by compiling with

```
-DGEOGRAPHICLIB_GEODESIC_ORDER=3
```

The accuracy is then 0.04 mm, i.e.,
comparable to, but slightly better than, Vincenty.

A cookbook recipe for solving the equivalent problem on a sphere is
given by the Wikipedia entry on [great-circle navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation#Finding_way-points).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to some code that will do what you are looking for, but will require a bit of work to use:

[Inverse and Forward Azimuth Algorithms](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/)

The source code is in Fortran so you will have to convert it to the format of your choice.  I have used these algorithms in the past without any problems but you will need to test them to determine if they are accurate enough for your needs.

Comment: These, according to the documentation, are the Vincenty algorithms cited in the question.