# Landsat 8 azimuth view angle

Tags: landsat-8, azimuth

I'm starting a new project and it's the first time I work with satellite imagery. Would anyone care to explain how to obtain the azimuth angle from the CORNER_ X/Y or the latitude/longitude data in the MTL file? I've seen it in other posts and I still don't get an idea on how to do it!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  If you have seen this in another post, then I recommend that you edit your Question to include a link to it, and expand upon where whatever instructions it gave started to lose you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two directly related questions are [Landsat Observation Zenith and Azimuth Angles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91062/landsat-observation-zenith-and-azimuth-angles?rq=1) and [Estimating Landsat 7 azimuth (heading)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92498/estimating-landsat-7-azimuth-heading?rq=1). However, they don't say *exactly* how to determine azimuth from two corner coordinates of a scene.

Assuming you do have the long-lat of two eastern or western corners, I believe the problem is now "simply" how to determine the azimuth given a pair of geographic coordinates. This is often called the *inverse geodetic problem* (or reverse geodetic problem). Two questions on *that* are [Geodesic measurements for short distances throughout US?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91007/geodesic-measurements-for-short-distances-throughout-us) and [Variation of algorithms to find point from another point with bearing and distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78651/variation-of-algorithms-to-find-point-from-another-point-with-bearing-and-distan). They go into some of the math/theory.

You may just need an online geodetic calculator, such as Movable-Type's [LatLong](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), the GeographicLib's [GeodSolve](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/GeodSolve) or the Australian [Vincenty_Inverse](http://www.ga.gov.au/geodesy/datums/vincenty_inverse.jsp).

Comment: For an approximate solution (less accurate in higher latitudes), you can just treat the lon-lat as though they were planar coords and use the simple plane trigonometry function, often called atan2().